# Open universal links (deep links) with XCUITest

Tags: xcuitest

I would like to create several tests for native iOS application. To be more precise, I want to test deep links. But I am not sure how to trigger deep link with XCUITest and I don't really see how `launch()` and `launcArguments` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication) can help me. Did anybody have a chance to open deep link with XCUITest?

Comment: What do you mean by a deep link? Please provide info.

Comment: @ablarg I meant to say "universal link" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/509/). Sorry for confusion, I used the word "deep" because this is how it's named in android world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set safari as app like this

   `let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")`
2. Open your email in safari
3. Tap on the link
4. Normally assert some element on app

Comment: thanks for suggestion. That's exactly where I ended up. Unfortunately, there seems to be no other way to it in XCUITest at the moment :(

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 14 using Spotlight seems to work well:

```
    private func open(_ urlString: String) {
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
        XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").swipeDown()
        let spotlight = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Spotlight")
        spotlight.textFields["SpotlightSearchField"].typeText(urlString)
        spotlight.buttons["Go"].tap()
    }
```

Comment: Should "Go" be capitalized?

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, and Xcode 14.3, new XCTest UI Testing API's are available which let you do this in an even easier way.

You can open your application with a specific URL: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/4108226-open

Or, open any URL in the default application for it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuisystem/4108234-open

Answer (score 1):

I never tried this, but this idea comes to my mind. Create a new dummy project/application that should only contain some links pointing to URLs that you expect your original app to open. From that new application, write some UI tests that tap a link, like this:

```
func testOpeningLinks() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.links["Some link text"].tap()
    // This is the place where your original app should be opened...

    // Find the XCUIApplication object:
    let originalApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "original.app.bundle.identifier")
    // You should be able to find some views from original app from here, eg. a button:
    let button = originalApp.buttons.element
}
```

This would work only if you have previously installed your app on the device/simulator where you're running your UI tests.